# calculate the absolute gradient of numeric values in a text file

Tags: python, r, data-wrangling

For some bioinformatics analysis, I have the value of some variable recorded at constant intervals stored in line-delimited text files. Each file might look like "10 \n 9 \n 8 \n 7 \n" or e.g. "28 \n 20 \n 5". I have more than 50k such files. For each file, I want to calculate the average slope for the experiment. Is there an easy, efficient way to this in python or R? I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a sample program , file sructure, for slope what are your reference point and the effort you put to solve the problem

Comment: Sample data looks like this
    
<file.txt>     
10   
9    
8    
7     
EOF     

I don't know how to get gradient so I haven't put much efforts